# How to count occurrence of each character in java string using Pattern Class(Regex)

Tags: java, regex, string, while-loop, pattern-matching

I am trying to find a number of Occurrence of each character on the given string.

- Expected output:  `t=2 e=1 s=1 i=1 n=1 g=1`
- Current output:`T=0 e=0 s=0 t=0 i=0 n=0 g=0`

Code:

```
String str = "Testing";
int count = 0;

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group().equals(str)) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(m.group() + "=" + count);
}
```

There are many ways of doing this but I am looking for Regex only, so how can we achieve that by using Regex. Any Help would be Appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a regex to solve your problem, if you are using Java8+ you can just use :

```
String input = "Testing";
Map<String, Long> result = Arrays.stream(input.split(""))
        .map(String::toLowerCase)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
```

outputs

```
{t=2, e=1, s=1, i=1, n=1, g=1}
```

---

Edit

mmm, Pattern in this case is useless I don't advice to use it in this problem, as an alternative solution using Pattern with results from Java9+ you can use :

```
String str = "Testing";
Pattern.compile(".").matcher(str)
        .results()
        .map(m -> m.group().toLowerCase())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
        .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " = " + v));
```

**Outputs**

```
t = 2
e = 1
s = 1
i = 1
n = 1
g = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but above part i know we can achieve with Map but can we do so with Pattern class also????

Comment: @Ab123 Pattern is useless here, I don't think that regex made to find number of occurrence of each character, can I ask you why you want to use Pattern in this problem?

Comment: OP means that if the string contains any special character (`testing1`), it should not be included.

Comment: what did you mean @Nikolas did you mean he want just lower and upper alphabets ?

Comment: @YCF_L: Input `testing123+` would still result `t=2 e=1 s=1 i=1 n=1 g=1` regardless the other symbols except `[a-zA-Z]`. Maybe that's why OP's stands for the Regex usage - an XY problem. My suggestion. Your answer is correct anyway +1.

Comment: @YCF_L I am just a beginner at java Regex so thought to use this in finding the Number of each Character, although we can find multiple occurence of Strings in a given string for eg. "Testing is good Testing is bad". we can Find multiple occurrence of Testing word so thought to use in Each  Character also.

Comment: I agree @Nikolas It is an XY, problem thank you for your uv

Comment: @Ab123 do you want occurrence of words or characters, and as I said before regex is useless in your problem, beside there are many other ways to learn regex

Comment: @YCF_L Characters only. Finding the Words i have done already.

Comment: @Ab123 can you share the way you find words, I think finding characters can be more easier

Comment: public class Regex_for_Multiple_occurrence_of_String {

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 
 {
  int count=0;
  
  String str = "Testing India Testing USA";
  
  String patternmatcher = "Testing";
  
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternmatcher,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
  
  while(matcher.find())
  {
   
      count++;
      
  }
  
 
      System.out.println("Testing="+count);
  
  
  
 }

     }

Comment: @Ab123 You are finding only `Testing` not all the words!!

Comment: ok, I got your point we cannot find all the Words/Characters present in String. Thanks.

Comment: @Ab123 please learn this https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/ and this https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems you will understand that regular expression is not always solve the problem good luck :)

Comment: @YCL_L Many Thanks.

Comment: @Ab123: Please mark one of the answers which helped you the most as accepted - it would say to the community that this question has found its answer already and help other users with a similar question with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways of achieving the result, but Regex is not a tool for this one. If you want to filter the characters and assure only `[a-zA-Z]` will be count, filter the unwanted characters with: `string = string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");`. Now back to your issue.

You need to split `String` to characters and a [`Map<Character, Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) you will store these characters and their number of occurrences. I suggest you use [`LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which assures the order of the insertion.

```
char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();
Map<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Now loop through the characters and save them to the map. If a character has already been stored, increment the value by one. This might be achieved with a procedural and traditional `for-loop` or since Java 8 you can use [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream).

Before Java 8:

```
for (char ch: charArray) {
    if(map.containsKey(ch)){
        map.put(ch, map.get(ch)+1);
    } else {
        map.put(ch, 1);
    }
}
```

After Java 8 (`string.split("")` returns an array of Strings, you need to map them to characters):

```
Map<Character, Long> map = Arrays
    .asList(string.split("")).stream().map(s -> s.charAt(0))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
```

In both cases the output will be the same:

```
System.out.println(map); // prints {t=2, e=1, s=1, i=1, n=1, g=1}
```